# Is the set of indices of all total computable function subset of K the halting set?

Tags: logic, computability

Consider the set of indices of all total computable functions
R = $\{m|\phi_{m}(x)\downarrow \forall x\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Is $R\subset K=\{x|\phi_{x}(x)\downarrow\}$?

My argument is that when $\phi_{m}$ is total, $\phi_{m}(m)\downarrow$ and hence $m\in R$ and $m \in K$. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you’re not wrong.

Comment: This is indeed correct. It is a basic rule of logic that if $\forall x \in \mathbb{N} (P(x))$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $P(m).